# Submit a Rails Form_tag without button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I created a search in rails using a form_tag and submit button. This works fine. However I would like to remove the submit button and move it into the Navbar

```
<h1>Search for Photos</h1>

<div id="photos_search">
  <%= form_tag search_photos_path do %>
    <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search], {:placeholder => "Type Space For Search Options"}) %>
    <button id='submit_search' style="font-size: 12px;">Search</button>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is the new code I added to my navbar

```
<%= form_tag search_photos_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:search, params[:search], {:placeholder => "Search", :class=>"search-query", :id=>"photo_search"}) %>

<% end %>
```

This is the Jquery wrote to find out when a user hits enter in the search form.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //Handles menu drop down
  $('#photo_search').keydown(function(evnt){
    if(evnt.keyCode === 13){
      console.log(evnt.keyCode)
    }
  });
});
```

What am I missing? Or should I do this a different way.

Thank you!

Comment: What happens if you press `Enter` inside the textfield?

Answer (score 0):

Wrong selector looks like, you have `#photo_search` instead of `#photos_search`.

Try adding `keydown` when the focus is on the text field:

```
$("#photos_search form input[type='text']").keydown(function(evnt){
    if(evnt.keyCode === 13){
      console.log(evnt.keyCode)
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that this does not yet submit the form, it only logs the `keyCode` which I believe was not working for you.  Also, I suggest that you assign an `id` attribute to the search text field so that your selector looks cleaner and selection is quicker.

Comment: My console outputs 13 for the enter press and my URL is Changed from http://localhost:3000/photos/1  to   http://localhost:3000/photos/1?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=mGgXIUlL1oRl3iFT6yse3a0iK8lBZcKHetqov%2FlfP44%3D&search=test

Comment: Right, so what would you like it to do?  Not submit the form?  Please update your question with what's not working after this stage.